# How can i use *ngif in angular to change div class

Tags: angular

I have the need to change the class of a div based on some condition. How can i use *ngif to achieve that ? I use this code which works fine in my template.

```
<div *ngIf="quickSearchTypeOptionConfigId && isGridReady" class="col-md-4 m-auto">
```

But i have a div above this div which is currently

```
<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
```

What my need this to be is if ***ngIf="quickSearchTypeOptionConfigId && isGridReady"** true true then

```
<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
```

else

```
<div class="col-md-12 m-auto">
```

is there a way to do this other then do 2 *ngif's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you
`[ngClass]="(quickSearchTypeOptionConfigId && isGridReady)?'col-md-8 m-auto':'col-md-12 m-auto'"`

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use ngClass like this:
`[ngClass]="[quickSearchTypeOptionConfigId && isGridReady ? 'col-md-8 m-auto' : 'col-md-12 m-auto']"`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

- `[class.myClass]="condition"` or
- `[style.attribute]="condition"` / `[style.attribute.unit]="condition"` or
- `[ngClass]="condition ? 'ifConditionClass' : 'elseConditionClass' (or empty string)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ngClass` attribute to check for conditions and assign CSS classes based on the result.

```
<div [ngClass]="{[quickSearchTypeOptionConfigId && isGridReady] ? 'col-md-8 m-auto' : 'col-md-12 m-auto'"}"></div>
```